# Navigate to different View depending on user input

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am asking the user for permission to access his location and would like to redirect him to ViewA if he accepts or ViewB if he refuses to give location access.
What would be the best way to go around this? Thanks in advance.

**VIEW**

```
struct UserPermissionView: View {
@ObservedObject var viewModel: UserPermissionViewModel

init(viewModel: UserPermissionViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            WeatherViewProperties.bgColors["clear sky"]
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image("weatherpermission")
                    Text("Hey! We need permission to access your location!").fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true).font(.title)
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.80)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.viewModel.requestAuthorisation()
                    }) {
                        Text("Grant Location")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
class UserPermissionViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
@Published var authorisationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = .notDetermined

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
}

public func requestAuthorisation(always: Bool = false) {
    if always {
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to push another view on the navigation stack? Or just replace the current view?

Comment: @pawello2222 I'd like to replace the current view, the UserPermissionView is basically a one time thing, and won't be navigating back to it once the user accepts or refuses location access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `@ViewBuilder`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: UserPermissionViewModel

    init(viewModel: UserPermissionViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            content
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    var content: some View {
        switch viewModel.authorisationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            requestPermissionView
        case .denied:
            Text("denied")
        default:
            Text("...")
        }
    }

    var requestPermissionView: some View {
        ZStack {
            WeatherViewProperties.bgColors["clear sky"]
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! Beautifully written code and thank you.